# Parameterisation for login feature in Karate

Tags: karate

I want to parameterise the login feature file so that is can be used for multiple user credentials. Can anyone please help me here? Below is the code that I am using:

Given url baseUrl
 And form field username = 'admin'
 And form field password = 'admin'
 When method GET
 Then status 200

I want to parameterise the value for username and password so that it can be passed from another feature file and can be reused again.

Comment: sounds like you have not read the documentation. please do so - because it will save yourself (and others) a lot of time. a specific answer to your question can be found here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks for the suggestion. I went through the documentation and tried using the code but I am still facing the issue. Below is the code that I am using:

Given url baseUrl
And form field j_username = username
And form field j_password = password
When method GET
Then status 200

And I am calling the feature file as mentioned below:

* call read(‘classpath:Login.feature’) {username: ‘admin’, password: ‘admin’}

Comment: I am getting the following error on calling the file:

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: test.feature:54 - javascript evaluation failed: 'admin', password: ‘admin'}, <eval>:1:17 Expected ; but found :
'admin', password: ‘admin'}
                 ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 17
 at ✽.* call read('classpath:Login.feature'){username: 'admin', password: ‘admin'}

Comment: time for you to follow this process, no one can help you otherwise: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue